# Breaking List int sub lists-Python

Tags: python, list

```
lst  = [[170,True],[210,False],[410,True],[170,True]...]
```

From this list I need extract into.

```
sublist1  = [170,210,410,170,..]

sublist2  = [True, False, True, True..]
```

How can I obtain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from `zip(*)` (which returns tuples) you can also use two list comprehensions:

```
sublist1 = [i[0] for i in lst]
sublist2 = [i[1] for i in lst]
```

Answer (score 5):

You may simply use :

```
sublist1, sublist2 = zip(*lst)
```

Comment: Cool trick @ZdaR.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map()` function like this:

```
lst  = [[170,True],[210,False],[410,True],[170,True]]
sublist1 = map(lambda n: n[0], lst)
sublist2 = map(lambda n: n[1], lst)
```

Comment: Depends on the Python version. In python 3.x you need to cast these `map`s to `list`s.

Comment: You are right :), I ran this code on python 2.7, Thanks!